# Mongo import data type

Tags: mongodb, grails

I am importing data into mongodb by this command

```
mongoimport -d dataBase --collection ip2location --type csv --file "/home/oodles/git/csv/IP2LOCATION-LITE-DB11.CSV" --fields _id,ipFrom,ipTo,countryCode,countryName,regionName,cityName,latitude,longitude,zipCode,timeZone
```

import is successfull
but the problem is

```
db.ip2Location.find().pretty()
```

getting

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("52be7f25c80e0735273985bf"), ///here is requirement need "_id" : NumberLong(1)
    "ipFrom" : NumberLong(16777216),
    "ipTo" : NumberLong(16777471),
    "countryCode" : "AU",
    "countryName" : "AUSTRALIA",
    "regionName" : "QUEENSLAND",
    "cityName" : "SOUTH BRISBANE",
    "latitude" : -27.48333,
    "longitude" : 153.01667,
    "zipCode" : 4101,
    "timeZone" : "+10:00"
```

first line is  "_id" : ObjectId("52be7f25c80e0735273985bf"),
but I need like this: "id" : NumberLong(1)

cvs data sample

```
"16777216","16777471","AU","AUSTRALIA","QUEENSLAND","SOUTH BRISBANE","-27.483330","153.016670","4101","+10:00"
```

Comment: Where should the `NumberLong(2)` come from?

Comment: Can you include some sample lines from your CSV file?  Based on your `--fields` list, the first field in each line should be used for the `_id`.  Also, what version of mongoimport are you using: `mongoimport -version`?

Comment: mongoimport version 2.0.4

Comment: db.ip2Location.findById(id as Long).pretty(). try this.

Comment: NB: there have been significant improvements in performance and features since MongoDB 2.0.4 and I would definitely recommend upgrading to the latest production version (currently MongoDB 2.4.8).

Answer (score 1):

> csv data sample
>
> "16777216","16777471","AU","AUSTRALIA","QUEENSLAND","SOUTH BRISBANE","-27.483330","153.016670","4101","+10:00"

The sample line doesn't match the list of `--fields` provided; it has one field less. The first field should be the `_id` you want to use (or `1` per your example).

Corrected line:

> 1, "16777216","16777471","AU","AUSTRALIA","QUEENSLAND","SOUTH BRISBANE","-27.483330","153.016670","4101","+10:00"

I tested and this works as expected in MongoDB 2.0.4.

I can't reproduce your results of having the `_id` added automatically with the first field value missing; when I tried with MongoDB 2.0.4 it assigned values to fields in the order listed so that the `_id` became 16777216, `ipFrom` was 16777471, etc.  I suspect you may have been viewing a document inserted in an earlier `mongoimport` run where your `--fields` list did not include `_id`.

You should also be aware that `mongoimport` only **inserts** data (it does not do updates or upserts). If there is already a document with the given `_id` than `mongoimport` will ignore that line of your CSV.

An easier way to keep the fields and CSV data in sync is to have the list of fields as the first line in your CSV and then use `mongoimport --headerline ...` instead of `--fields`.